# Installing windows on GPT partition

Tags: windows-7, installation, partitioning

I want to install windows on disks04 partition but its giving me error "Windows cannot installed on this partition of GPT style"

how can i convert a partition that will work for windows installation.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft erroneously conflates *has an EFI partitioned hard disc* with *has EFI firmware*.  This is, of course, clearly wrong.  It's quite possible — and indeed is becoming ever more desirable these days — to have an EFI partitioned disc on a machine that has old non-EFI firmware.

One of the several consequences of this error is that the Windows NT 6.1 installer has to be invoked from an install medium that has in turn been bootstrapped from EFI firmware, in order for it to accept the idea of installing Windows NT 6.1 to a disc partitioned with the EFI partitioning scheme.  Unfortunately, if the Windows NT install disc is bootstrapped in the old PC98 way the installer will think that there's no EFI firmware, and so declare that it cannot support EFI partitioned hard discs.

When you boot the Windows NT 6.1 install disc on an Intel Mac, that's exactly what happens.  The Mac's *compatibility support module* bootstraps the install disc in the old PC98 way.  [The Microsoft documentation explains how the installation CD-ROM is in fact dual-boot.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/hardware/gg463144.aspx)  But unfortunately when a CSM is present the CSM picks the wrong — i.e. non-EFI — image on the disc to bootstrap from.

[As Rod Smith explains](http://rodsbooks.com./bios2uefi/index.html), one therefore has to manually construct a Windows NT 6.1 install disc that bootstraps in the new EFI way.  The Windows NT 6.1 installer will then allow installation to an EFI partitioned hard disc.

Answer (score 0):

Only 64-bit Windows 7 can be installed into a GPT-partitioned disk directly. Either get a 64-bit version (if you are trying to install 32-bit), or try something like Boot Camp.

(You cannot convert the disk to MBR, because that would make Mac OS X unbootable.)

Comment: yes I am trying 64bit version

Comment: I am using 64bit version but still its giving me same error.

Comment: Out of interest. According to this MS link it should work: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463525

Comment: "Q-Can Windows 7, Windows Vista, and Windows Server 2008 read, write, and boot from GPT disks?...A-Yes, all versions can use GPT partitioned disks for data. Booting is only supported for 64-bit editions on UEFI-based systems". Must be 64bit and have uefi bios.