# Windows cannot install to GPT?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, windows-8-preview, gpt

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 x64 onto a 500GB SATA (Seagate Barracuda ES.2) drive.
I have downloaded Windows 8 Developer preview x64 onto a USB stick and I can't install it on a NTFS partition I created in Ubuntu with GParted.
The error says that Windows cannot be installed onto the partition because the partition is GPT.
My motherbaord is an Asus P8Z68-V LE and it supports UEFI, but i have no idea whether this is enabled.
Gparted shows me this: [image]
How can I determine whether Windows 8 is using UEFI?

Can I install Windows without wiping the entire HDD?

Comment: The Windows partition has to be first, I believe.

Comment: @satyrwilder Is there any way to do that without wiping Linux?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows Vista and 7, and presumably 8, only support installing to a GPT disk when the installer is booted using UEFI rather than BIOS emulation.  This is a configuration setting in your "BIOS" (really a misnomer on a UEFI system).

Consult your motherboard's manual to find out how to boot from the install media without using BIOS emulation.  (And make sure your install media actually *supports* booting that way — IIRC, it should contain a directory called `EFI`, containing a file named `bootx64.efi`.

Comment: The USB only has:       bootmgr.efi
efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot.efi
efi/microsoft/boot/cdboot_noprompt.efi
efi/microsoft/boot/memtest.efi

Comment: [Psst!](http://superuser.com/a/382650/38062)

Comment: @Tim, I might be wrong about the requirement for a `bootx64.efi` file; I haven't found any comprehensive documentation on the EFI boot process and all its possibilities.  But AFAIK, `bootx64.efi` is the "default bootloader" for a disk, used as a fallback when the machine doesn't have any NVRAM entries defining other `.efi` files to boot from.  (When you install Windows, it should create an NVRAM entry to boot something like `Microsoft\boot\bootmgfw.efi`.)