# Installing Windows7 with Fedora17 on UEFI system

Tags: windows-7, installation, fedora, uefi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install Windows 7 x64 on GPT?](https://superuser.com/questions/324067/how-to-install-windows-7-x64-on-gpt)

1. I made a Windows 7 installation on 750 GB disk so that Windows 7 used 50 GB where it created 100 MB NTFS system partition and 48.7 GB for Windows 7 installation.
2. Then I tried to install Fedora 17 and gave the option *use free space* and the installer threw an error saying **There is no BIOS Boot Stage1 partition**. I don't know how to create the EFI boot partition.
3. So I chose the option *Use entire disk*, and it created 200 MB EFI boot partition, 500 MB /boot and all other space was an LVM partition with /, swap and /home
4. I deleted the LVM, created **50 GB free space** and from the rest I made the new LVM with the same partitions, and installed the Fedora 17 system.
5. Then I booted the Windows 7 installation DVD, and selected the **50gb free space** to install on it, but it cannot continue because it is a GPT partition or something.

What can I do? How can i install Windows 7 with Fedora 17 dual boot in UEFI?